# getopt always return -1 if begin from third arguments

Tags: c, objective-c

I'm making a simple console that do something based on the command of the second argument. Below is the simplified code. My console however doesn't print any `NSLog`, and after checking, `opt` is always `-1`.

Usage is `myconsole firstMethod -t "this is a test string"`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

    NSString *stringArgument = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", argv[1]];

    if([stringArgument caseInsensitiveCompare:@"firstMethod"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        extern char *optarg;
        extern int optind;
        int opt;

        while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "t:")) != -1) {
            switch (opt){
                case 't':
                    NSLog(@"Case t");
                break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Default");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this failed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first argument is firstMethod, which since it doesn't start with a dash isn't an option, thus `getopt()` returning -1 like it's documented to do when there are no (more) options...

Comment: @Shawn any workaround for that?

Comment: Which platform? For linux/glibc: _By default,  getopt()  permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end._. But on other platforms, it may differ

Comment: It's on jailbroken iOS, objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-option arguments have to go at the end in general. GNU `getopt()` moves these to the end automatically by default, but your implementation does not have this feature, so `getopt()` stops processing at the first non-option argument.

If you *always* have the first argument as non-option (for example, a single command name), you can pass a modified (advanced by one argument) argument vector to `getopt()` like this:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc-1, argv+1, "t:")) != -1){
```

Then the first argument (which is non-option in your case) should be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Foundation` classes instead of `getopt` if you are developing a console app in Objective-C. With `NSUserDefaults` you can find the value for `t` much easier:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *valueForT = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"t"];
NSLog(@"%@", valueForT);
```

To check if user passed **firstMethod** to your console app use `NSProcessInfo`:

```
NSArray<NSString*> *arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
if (arguments.count >= 2) {
    NSLog(@"%@", arguments[1]);
}
```